# Get Corresponding Value in Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, key-value

Python noob that struggles with iterating through dictionaries/lists so bear with me:

list of dictionaries:

```
l = 
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'cream'},
{'id': 2, 'name': 'sugar'},
{'id': 3, 'name': 'mint'}]
```

Depending on the value of the name, I want to select the value of the corresponding id from the list.

For example, if I select "cream", I want 1. "Sugar" I want 2, etc. etc.

Easy way to do this preferably via list comprehension?

Comment: `[item['id'] for item in l if item['name'] == 'cream']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not have the *full* picture but I can see nothing in your question that actually *needs* a list of dictionaries. In fact, the structures you have allow for an item to have *multiple* IDs:

```py
myList = [
    { 'id':   1, 'name': 'cream' },
    { 'id':   2, 'name': 'sugar' },   # duplicates
    { 'id': 999, 'name': 'sugar' },   #   here.
    { 'id':   3, 'name': 'mint'  }
]
```

If all you need to do is map strings to an identifier, a *single* dictionary can do that:

```py
lookup = {'cream': 1, 'sugar': 2, 'mint': 3}
```

Then you could just use `lookup['cream']` to do the translation.

---

If you *do* need that specific data structure you specified, you can just use something like:

```py
[aDict['id'] for aDict in myList if aDict['name'] == 'cream']
```

to get a list of matches, and you'll need to decide what to do if there are multiples, such as getting just the first one:

```py
def getIdFor(haystack, needle):
    matches = [aDict['id'] for aDict in haystack if aDict['name'] == needle]
    if len(matches) == 0: return None
    return matches[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you probably want to do:

```
def selection(list_of_dicts, name_value):
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        if d["name"] == name_value:
            return d["id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'cream'},
     {'id': 2, 'name': 'sugar'},
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'mint'}]


input_name = input("name?")

result = [x["id"] for x in l if input_name == x["name"]]
print(result)
```

This would be the corresponding list comprehension. I don't think comprehensions are the best way to do this, since you don't want a list, but you requested it.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension doesn't feel like the appropriate way to do this, but I've created some code that uses it, since that's what you've requested:

```
l = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'cream'},
{'id': 2, 'name': 'sugar'},
{'id': 3, 'name': 'mint'}]

def get_id(l, name):
  new_list = [item for item in l if item['name'] == name]
  if len(new_list) == 0:
    return None
  return new_list[0].get('id')

print(get_id(l, 'cream'))
```

Output

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the source data modifications are rare compared to the lookup operations, it would make sense to generate a new dictionary with the exact mapping your are looking for, to avoid doing a full scan on each lookup:

```
l = 
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'cream'},
{'id': 2, 'name': 'sugar'},
{'id': 3, 'name': 'mint'}]

remapped = {item['name']:item['id'] for item in l}
# then
remapped['cream'] # -> 1
remapped['suger'] # -> 2
```